# Telegram API How to get chat participants?

Tags: telegram

This is not the Bot API, but the Telegram API!

I'm looking for a way to get chat participants.
Private chat (two participants), group chat (many participants).

Also, I want to get them through an **API request**, not through "Update".

The first thing I do is [GetDialogs](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getDialogs) - this way I get a list of dialogs that the account has and their ids.

Next, I tried to get the list of participants using different methods, but none of them could get the participants of the private chat (one-to-one)

[GetFullChat](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getFullChat) - It seems to be suitable and returns **chatFull.participants** - but it seems to be unsuitable for private chats, as it constantly returns an error(**CHAT_ID_INVALID**)

What API method will allow me to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Private chats (you-to-user) - have the same id as the user with whom you have this chat. id of private chats are unique to your account, but not unique to telegram (most likely the real id is hidden on the server)

Unfortunately, I have no official confirmation.

For groups and channels, it's suitable:
[channels.channelParticipants](https://core.telegram.org/constructor/channels.channelParticipants)
You may need to add "-100" in front of the id.

You may also find [this](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/concepts/entities.html) useful.